# Django Invalidate Form Test If Extra Field Supplied

Tags: django, django-forms, django-testing, django-tests

I have had some issue where a leak of User variables onto the registration form allowed users to set these on user creation.

**Can I ensure through testing that this will not be possible again?**

Let's say for example I don't want it to be possible that users can set their own 'coupon_code'. How would I test for that?

Accounts/forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import User

class RegisterUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True, help_text='Required.')

    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'password1', 'password2', 'email')
        exclude = ('coupon_code',)
```

Accounts/tests/test_forms.py:

```
from django.test import TestCase

from Accounts.forms import RegisterUserForm, UpdateUserForm

# Create your tests here.
class RegisterUserFormTest(TestCase):
    #@classmethod
    #def setUpTestData(cls):
    # Set up non-modified objects used by all test methods
    def valid_data(self):
        return {'username':'abc', 'email':'abc@abc.com', 'password1': 'test123hello', 'password2':'test123hello'}

    def test_register_user_form_cannot_set_coupon_code(self):
        data = self.valid_data()
        data['coupon_code'] = '42'
        form = RegisterUserForm(data=data)
        self.assertFalse(form.is_valid())
```

Currently the above test fails, as the form is considered valid, even though excluded field is present

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, the `is_valid()` method ignores extra data passed to Form. If `is_valid()` it returns `True`, that only means data was valid for the prescribed fields, and only those fields will be in the cleaned_data dictionary ([Django docs about this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/api/#accessing-clean-data)).

I think the test you want to perform must be done on the view function that uses this form. It could look like this:

```
from django.test import Client

def test_your_user_creation_view(self):

    c = Client()

    c.post(reverse(<your view name>),<valid data with 'coupon_code':42>)

    new_user = User.objects.get(username='abc')

    self.assertTrue(new_user.coupon_code != '42')
    self.assertEqual(new_user.coupon_code,<your default value for coupon_code>)
```